# Prevent self-closing tags in XML produce by SQL Server after concatenate

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Self-closing tags can remove from XML by adding TYPE at the end.

```
SELECT N'' as [Col1],
       N'' as [Col2] 
FOR XML PATH('Rows'),TYPE
```

But if we want to concatenate two XMLs it comes back

```
DECLARE @xml1 XML= 
  (SELECT N'' as [Col1],
          N'' as [Col2] 
   FOR XML PATH('Rows'),TYPE);

DECLARE @xml2 XML= 
  (SELECT N'' as [Col1],
          N'' as [Col2] 
   FOR XML PATH('Rows'),TYPE);

select  @xml1,@xml2
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
```

Result is

```
<Rows>
  <Col1 />
  <Col2 />
</Rows>
<Rows>
  <Col1 />
  <Col2 />
</Rows>
```

Instead of

```
<Rows>
    <Col1></Col1>
    <Col2></Col2>
</Rows>
<Rows>
    <Col1></Col1>
    <Col2></Col2>
</Rows>
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Curious to know why it's a concern?

Comment: Semantically there is no difference... You should not rely on this difference, because any manipulation can change this. Even if you get the needed output, the next time it might be different...

Comment: Then why is that result with TYPE and WITHOUT TYPE is different?

Comment: They are different, in that when self-closed, xml.modify() fails to update elements that are null or empty. I would prefer to modify() instead of delete() then insert(), which I am forced to do.

Answer (score 0):

> Then why is that result with TYPE and WITHOUT TYPE is different?

To answer this: It is not really *different* as it is semantically *the same*.

An XML is not stored as the *mark-up* string you see but as an hierarchically organised physical table. Whenever you tell the engine *"Show me the XML!"* this will be re-created - just for presentation. The engine will - in most cases - choose the *cheapest* format.

I cannot really look *into the engine* but I assume that

```
SELECT N'' as [Col1],
       N'' as [Col2] 
FOR XML PATH('Rows'),TYPE
```

...works like this:

- Okay, we open the element Col1 with `<Col1>`.
- Now we enter the content - oh there's no content
- No problem let's close it with `</Col1>`
- Okay, a new element. Let's open it with `<Col2>`
- and so on.

The final `SELECT` will return the XML just as it was created.

But this code

```
DECLARE @xml1 XML= 
  (SELECT N'' as [Col1],
          N'' as [Col2] 
   FOR XML PATH('Rows'),TYPE);

DECLARE @xml2 XML= 
  (SELECT N'' as [Col1],
          N'' as [Col2] 
   FOR XML PATH('Rows'),TYPE);
```

... will create variables of native type XML (the `,TYPE` would not make any difference here). The variables will be stored in the spoken hierarchical format. Just try a simple `SELECT @xml1`. This will return the *cheaper* format with self-closing elements too.

Now you combine them. That means, that the engine will create the XML's content internally and create the human-readable output (the thing we usually call "XML") *on demand*.

```
select  @xml1,@xml2
FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE
```

Again you can do this witout `,TYPE` too...